# Finding all metrics of set $X=\{1,2,3\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have the following problem where I'm lost a bit.

> Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $(X,d)$ be a metric space. List all the metrics
>   $d$ of $X$ and show that they are equivalent. (Hint: construct a
>   $3\times 3$ table)

I'm not sure how to solve this problem, but aren't there infinitely many of the metrics? I mean if $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ then isn't also $d(x,y)=c|x-y|$ allowed metric, where $c\geq0$. The axioms of metric $d$ state that

> 1. $d(x,x)=0$
> 2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
> 3. $d(x,y)\geq 0$
> 4. $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

So all the metrics must fulfill these conditions. If they are equivalent, then they induce the same topology of $\tau$ of $X$, that is the set $\mathcal{B}$ of bases consisting from $r$-balls 
$$B(a,r)=\{\;x\in X\mid d(a,x)<r\}$$

must be equal for all these possible metrics $d$. I'm not sure how I should use the hint to help me. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: One-point sets on a finite metric space $X$ are clearly open (and closed), so any set $U\subset X$ is open (and closed); that is, any metric on $X$ is equivalent to the discrete topology.

Comment: In item (3), you're missing the fact that equality holds iff $x = y$. Otherwise, you just have a pseudometric space (which isn't even necessarily, say, Hausdorff).

Comment: Thank you @anomaly :) sry about that, I was kinda sloppy on writing the axioms x)

Comment: You're right that for any metric $d$, a scaling of $d$ by a positive constant is also a metric, so there are infinitely many.  I think the point of the question is that you can list them all using only finitely many constants.

Comment: Thank you @PaulMcKenney for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the table as they said. This is what you get from the first three

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 
1 &0  & |u| & |v|\\ 
2 & |u| & 0 & |w|\\ 
3 & |v| & |w| & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

and the last is just a triangle requirement $|u| \leq |v|+|w|$, $|v| \leq |w|+|u|$, $|w| \leq |u|+|v|$ together with the cases when a triangle degenerates into a line (when one of the equation is in the form $|a| = |b|+|c|$) except the trivial cases when any $u=0$ or $v=0$ or $w=0$ because that would imply that two elements are the same.

This covers all possible metrics.

1. So take a triangle and the distance between vertices. $|u| < |v|+|w|$, $|v| < |w|+|u|$, $|w| < |u|+|v|$
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
    & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 
   1 &0  & |u| & |v|\\ 
   2 & |u| & 0 & |w|\\ 
   3 & |v| & |w| & 0
   \end{bmatrix}$$
2. Take a line and distance between end points and any point in between.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 
1 &0  & |u| & |v|\\ 
2 & |u| & 0 & |u|+|v|\\ 
3 & |v| & |u|+|v| & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 
1 &0  & |u| & |u|+|v|\\ 
2 & |u| & 0 & |v|\\ 
3 & |u|+|v| & |v| & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 
1 & 0  & |u|+|v| & |u|\\ 
2 & |u|+|v| & 0 & |v|\\ 
3 & |u| & |v| & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! =)

Comment: The last one is not a metric.

Comment: I thought after you wrote "This covers all possible metrics" that would have been the end of your solution? I am not clear beginning from your numbering i.e., 1 and 2. How did you compute the entries of the three tables in point 2? Could you please elaborate a lil bit for me?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try also answer this question with my own words. Does it make any sense? Here goes:

> Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Because $(X,d)$ is a
>   metric space we can find such a set $\mathcal{B}$ of $r$-balls that
>   $\mathcal{B}=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$ which are open subsets of $X$.
>
> Clearly these open subsets of $X$ form a basis for the discrete
>   topology of $X$. In other words all the metrics on $X$ are equivalent
>   with each other because they all induce the discrete topology on $X$.

Comment: Could you give an answer to my post above if you have any idea under userr195934 solution?